# Why Spark Drivers don't run when Applications run?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm a beginner trying to learn about the behavior of applications and drivers by going through some examples. I'm starting off with:

- Running a standalone cluster manager
- Running a single master calling `./sbin/start-master.sh`
- Running a single worker calling `./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://localhost:7077`
- Launching a test application in client mode by calling:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --master spark://localhost:7077 \
  ./examples/src/main/python/pi.py
```

According to the [Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html#glossary):

> The process running the main() function of the application and creating the SparkContext

My takeaway from this is there should be at least one driver program that runs when an application runs. However, I'm not seeing this in the web UI for the master:

- **Alive Workers:** 1
- **Cores in use:** 4 Total, 0 Used
- **Memory in use:** 15.0 GB Total, 0.0 B Used
- **Applications:** 0 Running, 1 Completed
- **Drivers:** 0 Running, 0 Completed
- **Status:** ALIVE

*Shouldn't I expect to see 1 driver running or completed?* I've included some config details below.

---

**./conf/spark-defaults.conf:**

```
spark.master=spark://localhost:7077
spark.eventLog.enabled=true
spark.eventLog.dir=./tmp/spark-events/
spark.history.fs.logDirectory=.tmp/spark-events/
spark.driver.memory=5g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running an interactive shell, e.g. pyspark (CLI or via an IPython notebook), by default you are running in `client` mode. 
Client mode does not triggers Driver program but `cluster` mode does.

NOTE :  AFAIK you cannot run `pyspark` or any other interactive shell in cluster mode.

So try running the application in cluster mode using `--deploy-mode cluster`

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --master spark://localhost:7077 \
  --deploy-mode cluster
  ./examples/src/main/python/pi.py
```

Comment: You are correct. Cluster deploy mode is currently not supported for python applications on standalone clusters. So, I tried deploying in cluster mode while launching an application jar instead. This successfully submitted a driver. Thanks for your help!